# JavaScript function drawing arc at incorrect angle

Tags: javascript, svg, setattribute

I'm trying to create an arc that points to a specific angle, width (in degrees), and *distance from center* (so that the arcs don't overlap).

The included snippet calls JavaScript function `DrawLine` that *draws the line*, but at the incorrect angle. Also, the arc changes its angle when the `DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER` variables change, and that shouldn't happen.

I'm including a screenshot of what the angles *should* look like.

[image]

I'm also including how we interpret angles in a circle, and 310 degrees should point to the upper left. The javascript draws them pointing to the right.

[image]

```js
let svg = document.getElementById("icon");
function drawLine(azimuth, radius, length)
{
  let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  // Create an SVG <circle> element
  let line = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "circle");
  line.setAttribute("r", radius);
  line.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", length + ' ' + circumference);
  line.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + azimuth + ")");
  // Add it to the <svg> element
  svg.appendChild(line);
}

let DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER1 = 93,
DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER2 = 65,
DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER3 = 30,
DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER4 = 9;

drawLine(312, DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER1, 110);

drawLine(312, DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER2, 95);

drawLine(312, DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER3, 55);

drawLine(312, DISTANCE_FROM_CENTER4, 15);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 14;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icon" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
</svg>
```

Comment: From the image you post I would say that the length should be relative to the circumference. Besides you seams to have several circles with the same radius but different angle,

Comment: It doesn't seem to change the angle to me.  All the left edges are aligned, which is expected because you are passing the same value (200) to the function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure SVG considers 0 to be dead right.  I could check, but I'm pretty sure.  You can pass 0 to it for the angle and check, but I did try it a couple of times while I was looking at your code.  That's why I said I was just using your numbers.  I think you may be looking for -138 or 232.

Comment: If you want to pass it the angle you expect, you can adjust the azimuth inside the function, see my edit and let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to line up the middles of the segments, you'll have to calculate the angle.  The segment starts at 0 and the length is based on that starting point, and then when you rotate the segment the entire thing turns that amount.  Since you're passing the same transform value (200) to all the segments, they all turn the same amount, and so all of their starting points are still aligned.

So try this (I'm just using the values you were using in your snippet, not sure how these relate to the picture, which has a different number of segments and lengths and angles).  Calculate the percentage of arc that your segment comprises, and offset the rotation by half of that.

```js
let svg = document.getElementById("icon");
function drawLine(azimuth, radius, length) {
  
  let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  let arc = length / circumference * 360;
  
  let line = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "circle");
  line.setAttribute("r", radius);
  line.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${length} ${circumference}`);
  line.setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${azimuth-(arc/2)})`);
  
  svg.appendChild(line);
}

const arcs = [
  {azimuth: 200, dist: 93, length: 110},
  {azimuth: 200, dist: 65, length:  95},
  {azimuth: 200, dist: 30, length:  55},
  {azimuth: 200, dist:  9, length:  15},
  //{azimuth: 200, dist: 1,  length: 1.5}
];

arcs.forEach(el=>{drawLine(el.azimuth, el.dist, el.length)});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 14;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icon" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
</svg>
```

SVG thinks 0 is dead right, and that's where the path is going to start, so if you expect 312 to point toward the upper left, like your picture, and you also want to keep passing it 312, etc, I think you can just subtract 90 from the azimuth inside your function.  Like this:

```js
let svg = document.getElementById("icon");
function drawLine(azimuth, radius, length) {
  
  let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  let arc = length / circumference * 360;
  
  let line = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "circle");
  line.setAttribute("r", radius);
  line.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${length} ${circumference}`);
  line.setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${azimuth-(arc/2)-90})`);
  
  svg.appendChild(line);
}

const arcs = [
  {azimuth: 312, dist: 93, length: 110},
  {azimuth: 312, dist: 65, length:  95},
  {azimuth: 312, dist: 30, length:  55},
  {azimuth: 312, dist:  9, length:  15},
  //{azimuth: 312, dist: 1,  length: 1.5}
];

arcs.forEach(el=>{drawLine(el.azimuth, el.dist, el.length)});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 14;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icon" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is where the arc is drawn. At 312 degrees, the arc should point to the upper left. It's pointing to the right.

Comment: I added an image of a circle with the angles.